# Rmarkdown creates _site folder

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am currently using **rmarkdown** for creating an academic blog via Github server. Recently, I did something silly with *shell* and had to re-authenticate SSH key. After hours of frustration, I somehow managed to get the shell pushing and pulling again. But, whenever I attempt to *push* new changes, rmarkdown creates a new folder called **_site** and recreates existing files into that folder.

Prior to my silly mess up, rmarkdown saved all files in a folder called **public_policy**. Now, however, rmarkdown saves all files in the following address: "**.../public_policy/_site/**"

I hope my explanation is clear and comprehensible. Can anyone help this lost rookie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue by adding "**output_dir: .**" in the **_site.yml** file:

```
name: "my-website"
output_dir: .
navbar:
   title: "Blog Title"
   left:
     - text: "Home"
       href: index.html

output:
  html_document: 
    theme: cosmo
    css: css/style.css
```